# How to synamically display a div just above a textbox without using any containers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the scenario :

I have a few textboxes I want to display validation message in a tooltip or something similar. I do not want to use any plugin. How can this be done?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="check"   />
<input type="text" class="check"   />
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.check').on('blur',function(){
     var value=$(this).val();
    var validationdiv='<div class="tooltip-inner">'+value+'</div>'
    $(this).ShowAbove(validationdiv); //I know it does not exists

});
```

Comment: Use `before`, `$(this).before(validationdiv);`

Comment: @Tushar You know that might work. But It will keep on adding divs after divs each time. Can I somehow add and then remove it automatically after certain time interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert it after and use a timeout to remove it over time.

```
$('.check').on('blur',function(){
    var value=$(this).val();
    var validationdiv='<div class="tooltip-inner">'+value+'</div>'
    $(this).after(validationdiv);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.tooltip-inner').remove();
    }, 2000);
});
```

Also, you might want to put the input inside a container with a `position: relative` so you can use position absolute with a negative margin to offset the tooltip from the input field.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1yfpptew/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="check"   />
<input type="text" class="check"   />
```

**CSS**

```
div.tooltip-inner {
    background-color: #999;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.check').on('blur',function(){
    $(this).prev('div.tooltip-inner').remove();

    var position = $(this).position(),
        validationdiv = $('<div></div>')
            .addClass('tooltip-inner')
            .text($(this).val())
            .css({
                left: position.left,
                width: $(this).outerWidth()
            })
            .insertBefore($(this));
        validationdiv.css({
            top: position.top - validationdiv.height(),
            display: 'block'
        });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vmkhyt90/2/)

**NOTE**: The initial `display: none` is given to insert the tooltip into the dom in order to be able to calculate its height

Answer (score 0):

Use style like below for your message...

```
.validation-msg {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
}
```

Comment: This is going to show the message off screen as long as there is no container with `position: relative`.